# Ensure Derived Classes have property of appropriate type

Tags: c++, abstract-class, derived-class

I have an abstract base class (only data members and pure virtual functions within), for example a "Plotter" class.

I have two planned derived implementations, "NumberPlotter" and "WordPlotter," and each of them are mostly the same save for the fact that NumberPlotter has a member variable called "processor" that is of type "NumberProcessor" and WordPlotter has a member variable called "processor" that is of type "WordProcessor". Both of these *Processor classes are implementations of the abstract base class "Processor".

Is there a way to ensure that the *Plotter classes have a member variable called "processor" with a type of some implementation of *Processor at compile time, through their abstract base class? I cannot declare that the Plotter class has a variable of type Processor as the Processor has only pure virtual functions (it is an abstract type).

The Processor implementations have some of the same member variables, and so I would like to be able to make some basic assumptions when using the base Plotter class in the form of Plotter->Processor-> or even Plotter->Processor->Process().

Comment: Abstract classes can have data members (interfaces cannot), so you can add `Processor & processor;` member to your `Plotter` class

Answer (score 2):

The way you would do that is to define an abstract function like:

```
WordProcessor &getProcessor () = 0 ;
```

You can't really force a child class to have a member variable but you can force it to have a member function that depends upon having such a member variable.

Comment: I see. I considered that solution, and now it seems like that might be the best way to achieve this. Thanks